# How can I catch an inner exception which is only present on the parent's message?

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, ado.net

I'm trying to catch a `ORA-01013` exception in my code, but it's not appearing in the correct order in the caught exception. We have a `Trigger` in the database which will fire and log every time a `SERVERRROR` happens in our Oracle database. This `Trigger` is what is causing the problem, but I cannot modify it.

The Exception does not have any `InnerException`, but the exception I want to catch does appear in the `Message` of the thrown Exception.

This is the order of exceptions thrown, but only `ORA-04088` is thrown as the exception. The rest are just in that thrown exceptions `.Message` property, I suspect that it got swallowed up somewhere.

The Thrown Exception's `.Message` property:

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRIG_SERVER_ERRORS' // Don't want this
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 14
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation // Want this
```

The exception I want to catch is `ORA-01013`, but the thrown exception is `ORA-04088`. The exception thrown has no link to the wanted exception besides the `.Message` property.

So far I've come up with this,

```
try
{
    ...
    ...
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    // if(ex.Number = 01013) // This doesn't work since ex.Number is 04088
    // if(ex.GetBaseException().Number) // Doesn't work also since ORA-04088 is the Base Exception
    if (ex.Message.Contains("ORA-01013")) // I want to catch this
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("The request took too long to complete. Please add more parameters to search by, or reduce the date duration", ex);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new DataAccessException(99999, ex, "ORA-{0} exception occurred during the inline call to {1}.", ex.Number.ToString(), MethedInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that I'm forced to handle *any* `OracleException` that enters the catch block. I could add a `throw;` at the end of my if's or continue to wrap thrown exceptions in another, but I'd rather have to only `catch` on the specific type of exception *that has the Message text I'm after*. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# 6 introduced the [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-catch-statement) keyword for use with a `catch` block. This way, you can specify an expression to narrow down the exception you want to catch instead only filtering solely by its Type and writing `if()` logic inside the catch block.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (OracleException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("ORA-01013"))
{
    // do things with exception
}
```

I personally like this solution as:

1. It is much easier to skim over the code and see exactly *what kind* of exception you are asking for
2. You don't have a "catch all" bucket with many if's or switch statements inside.
3. Your catch line is very focused to this one particular style, meaning you can chain multiple of them on one `try` and order them in decreasing specificity.

As for your situation with inner exceptions not appearing - well, you're up the creek with that one. If the library developers don't give you a true InnerException object to work with, you're stuck with inspecting the string Message property.